# Using GDB Debugger to See Hidden Code

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I have been given a binary file with embedded C code which I cannot see when I run it in the GDB GCC Debugger. I imagine the C code has been hidden by the compilation / formation of the binary code. I have tried the following:

gdb> file myFile
gdb> list main

The output I get is:

myFile.c: No such file or directory

I know there is code written in C in this binary file. The executable runs when I type ./myFile

I have installed 32-bit libraries as this is needed for this situation and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The original source code is not embedded in the binary. You need a copy of the source tree somewhere and point GDB to it to see it. That is, if you don't have the source code already don't expect GDB to magically be able to produce it for you.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know of a copy of the source tree. Is there a way to locate this? I'm not familiar with it but I will research it now.

Comment: The author of the source code has to make it available to you. This is not a question anyone can answer for you with the available info.

Comment: There is not C code in this binary file.

Comment: Thank you immibis. There definitely is C code in the file. I stated that in my Post. I understand that it is not available to me as kaylum has explained.

Comment: No, there is no C code in the file. C code will be _compiled_ to machine code (which is a lossy process, because machine code are very basic instructions for the computer, such as "move this thing to there", without giving any of the big picture of the meaning of things you would get from reading C code), and that's what's in the file. Imagine that C code is a recipe, and that the machine code is the dish. There is no recipe in the dish afterwards. (And saying "I know there is English text embedded in it", just because the _recipe_ was written in English, is also not true then.)

Comment: And just for clarification: What the GDB debugger can usually do for you is taking a recipe you already have (the C code on your harddisk) _and_ the finished dish (the binary file you got out of the C code) and then show them side by side and tell you "this thing here is obviously the sauce, so please take a look at these lines in the recipe where it says 'mix cream with mashed tomatoes'". Had you not given GDB that recipe as well, it would say 'there is a sauce but I don't know what it is made from - can't find the recipe :(' and that's what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed message and explanation CherryDT. I appreciate it and understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be are a compilation issue. Try to look [option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) for debugging

```
$ gcc -g myFile.c -o myFile
$ gdb myFile
(gdb) list main
```

If you compile without `"-g"` option, the debugger will never show you th C code but only the assembly code.

In your case, if you run these commands, you will see the disassembled code

```
(gdb) info file
```

Then take the address of the entry point

```
Entry point: 0x(address)
```

For show disassembly code

```
(gdb) break 0x(address)
(gdb) run
```

When the breakpoint gets caught

```
(gdb) x/20i $pc
```